# font list causes 'expected "indent"'

Tags: stylus

When I try to compile the stylus below stylus throws a ParseError `expected "indent", got "outdent"`.

```
body
  font 18px Arial, ​sans-serif
```

If I remove *sans-serif*

```
body
  font 18px Aria
```

It compiles fine. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invisible `U+200B` (zero width space) character before `sans-serif`. If you remove it, all will be fine.